# normalisation in DBMS

Tags: database-design, normalization, data

For the relation schema R(A, B, C, D, E) with the following FDs

```
FD1: {A,B,C} → {D,E} 
FD2: {B,C,D} → {A,E} 
FD3: {C} → {D}
```

I Decomposed R into a set of BCNF relations.
I got candidate keys as {A,B,C}, {B,C,D} respectively.. how do I find the subset of {A,B,C}?

My solution :
FD3 violates BCNF. Decomposing R using FD3.

```
R1(C,D) with FDs: 
    FD3, 
    CK: {C} 
R2(A,B,C,E) 
    with new FD: {A,B,C} → E (Decomposed from FD1) , 
    CK: {A,B,C} {BC}+ = {BC}
```

- Not a candidate key {ABC}+ = {ABCDE}
- A candidate key {BCD}+ = {ABCDE}
- A candidate key Candidate Keys = {ABC}, {BCD}

The result of the decomposition consists of R1 and R2.

- But I was said there still exists a subset of `{A,B,C}` I’m unable to find it.

Comment: "find the subset of {A,B,C}" & "there still exists a subset of {A,B,C}" are not clear. Use correct technical terms. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. . Why are you stuck? You just showed that you have an algorithm to decompose.

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the FD are a *cover* of the functional dependencies of R, you can find a *minimal cover* of them:

```
B C -> A
B C -> E
C -> D
```

From this minimal cover, one can find easily the only candidate key, which is `{B, C}`.

As you have correctly said, the dependency `C -> D` violates the BCNF, so we can decompose R in R1, R2:

```
R1 = {C D}, with the the projected dependency C -> D, and C the only candidate key
R2 = {A B C E}, the projected dependencies B C -> A, B C -> E, and the only candidate key B C
```

Both R1 and R2 are in BCNF.

Comment: Since B C -> A and B C -> E are in the minimal cover of the dependencies of R, they hold also in R2, since all their attributes belong to R2.

Comment: These rules are part of the so-called normalization theory. This is described in many good books on databases. There are also some of them free on internet.